# eventOverlap is supposed to allow another event into a day that has a different tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Here's the code:

```js
    eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
        console.log("I am overlapping something");
            if (stillEvent.tags == ""|| movingEvent.tags == "") {
                        console.log("One of the events have no tag");
                        return true;
            } else {
                console.log("SE = " + stillEvent.tags + " ME = " + movingEvent.tags);
                $.each( stillEvent.tags.split(','), function( key, value ) {
                    var index = $.inArray( value, movingEvent.tags.split(',') );
                    var result = "";
                    if( index == -1 ) {
                        console.log("Found no similar tags");
                        result =true;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Similar tags at index:"+index);
                        result =false;
                    }
                    return result;
                });
            }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do, is when I drag an event above another day that contains an event as well, this function will compare the tags string they have (by splitting them) and looking at each individually.

If one or both of the events have no tags, it is allowed into the day.
Else, each of these are supposed to be compared per element
say X=["1","2","3"] and Y=["3","4","5"] both of these has 3, therefore it should return false. But if it finds no similar elements, like X = ["1"] and Y = ["2"] it should return true. False will disable eventOverlap, and true otherwise.

So I checked with the console. What's happening here is that even if it knows that there are no similar tags, eventOverlap is still not enabled. Only when the other event has no tag.

Might it be a flaw on my logic? Thanks!

Comment: I got a syntaxerror when i run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
...
eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
       if (stillEvent.tags == ""|| movingEvent.tags == "") {
                    console.log("One of the events have no tag");
                    return true;
        } else {
         for (i = 0; i<stillEvents.tags.length; i++){
                for(j = 0;j<movingEvent.tags.length,j++) { 
                   if (movingEvent.tags[j] == stillEvents.tags[i]){
                        return false;
                    }
                 }
           }
         return true;
         }
}
...
```